# objective-c add string to html bundle

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I searched Stackoverflow to see if this question has already been asked, but my search did not return any relevant questions/responses.  Hoping to get a hand (sorry this question has already been asked).

Here is my question:
- I have an HTML file (i.e., htmlpage.html) in my iOS main bundle
- in that HTML file are various "%@"s
- I have an NSString, str, that contains that value "Rule"

Question:
I would like to load the value of str into each occurrence of %@ in htmlpage.html.

Does anyone know if this is possible?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace substrings with the following method.

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target withString:(NSString *)replacement

//i.e.
myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%@" withString:str];
```

Also, you can get the contents of your html file with:

```
+ (id)stringWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error
```

Comment: Thank you for the response!  What if each %@ in the html file should be filled with a different string?  For instance, if the html file contains the code "<html><body>%@ - %@</body></html>" and I would like str1 to replace the first '%@' and str2 to replace the second '%@'?

Comment: There is no way to differentiate them, you'd have to do it by hand.

Comment: Okay, what I was hoping was that I could somehow use the HTML file like the stringWithFormat method.  I.e., stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", str1, str2 > stringWithFormat:htmlfile, str1, str2 where the first occurrence of %@ in htmlfile is replaced with str1, and the second with str2.

Not possible?